# Java ArrayList.removeAll()

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I want to make a section of code that takes a list of lists, splits it into sublists of 9 and remove numbers from all the lists in each of the sublists. However, when my code runs it removes numbers from all the lists, not just the section taken from the original list

```
for (int startingIndex = 0; startingIndex <= 8; startingIndex++) {
        int initialIndex = startingIndex * 9;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> gridRow = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        gridRow.addAll((posabilityGrid.subList(initialIndex, initialIndex+9)));
        System.out.println("gridrow - " + gridRow);
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (ArrayList<String> posability : gridRow) {
            if (posability.size() == 1) {
                numbers.add(posability.get(0));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("numbers - " + numbers);
        

        for (ArrayList<String> posability : gridRow) {
                posability.removeAll(numbers);
        }
        System.out.println("newgrid - " + gridRow);
```

edit:
When the starting index first equals 0:

> grid row - [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9]]
>
> numbers - [4, 3, 2, 9]

it then correctly prints out:

> newgrid - [[1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [], [], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], []]

However, when starting index equals 1 at the start:

> gridrow - [[1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1]]

instead of the expected

> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1]]

This section of the list has had the previous numbers removed from it for some reason when it should stay the same so the only the new set of numbers are subtracted

2nd edit:
I've added the line

```
numbers.clear();
```

but i still have the same problem.
I've printed out the numbers list and checked that it is cleared each time but the main list seems to be changed on the first "posability.removeAll(numbers);"

Edit 3:
I've solved it now, The problem was with the ArrayList and Sublists. Once I changed the list so a new ArrayList deepcopy is created rather then just referencing the old one the code works great.

```
List<List<String>> posabilityGridClone = posabilityGrid.stream().map(it -> new ArrayList(it)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        gridRow.addAll((Collection<? extends ArrayList<String>>) (posabilityGridClone.subList(initialIndex, initialIndex+9)));
```

Comment: To help make clear what you are trying to achieve, could you edit your question to include some sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Daniel Pryden, It's not really a duplicate. Even if you replace it with `new ArrayList(posabilityGrid.subList(initialIndex, initialIndex+9))` it will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Swanny: Can you [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? I suspect that the issue here is that you are re-using references to the same underlying storage.

Comment: @KonstantinLabun: OK, I've reopened and removed the duplicate. But since the answer below was marked as accepted, I think the duplicate is at least *part* of the problem, right? I do think this question is ultimately a duplicate, though.

Comment: @DanielPryden it's kind of tricky. Cause is similar but not the same. Will you close two questions with typos in variable names as duplicates if they have absolutely different code that solve different tasks?

Comment: @KonstantinLabun: If the *answer* to the question is the same in both cases, then yes, they should be closed as duplicates. Remember that the purpose of a duplicate answer is so that we can funnel questions at the highest-quality answer(s) possible. It's much better to have one "canonical" question that has high-quality, thorough answers, rather than to have similar questions answered in slightly different ways (with differing clarity and correctness!) hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `numbers.clear()` as the last line of your main cycle. You `numbers` array is persisted between cycles and it is the problem if I correctly understand what you expect to get.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I didn't saw numbers at first. I though it was created out of scope.

You problem is actually in this line:

```
gridRow.addAll((posabilityGrid.subList(initialIndex, initialIndex+9)));
```

When you create a sublist you have two problems here:

1) Sublist is just a view of the same array. (removing element from sublist affect original list)

2) Elements of array are references to another arrays. So when you run removeAll you actually remove it all from original arrays.

**What you need is to make deepcopy of you arrays of arrays and use it instead of original one.**

```
List<List<String>> posabilityGridClone = posabilityGrid.stream().map(it -> new ArrayList(it)).collect(Collectors.toList());
gridRow.addAll((posabilityGridClone.subList(initialIndex, initialIndex+9)));
```